# Why are all definitions of agile framework so handwave-y?

Tags: agile, definition

Take the wikipedia definition:

> Agile software development is an approach to software development under which requirements and solutions evolve through the collaborative effort of self-organizing and cross-functional teams and their customer(s)/end user(s).

so what is this saying? It's saying

> groups of developers work on changing problems and communicate with
> each other.

That doesn't give any description on how problems are solved,  the structure of teams (aside from the existence of groups), the management,  the target audience for agile, or even how it's implemented.  The entire wikipedia article reads like this.  like an advertisement.

Now I'm no newbie to software engineering, and I can clearly see that this definition is meant to stir as many buzzwords as possible, meaning that its meant to appeal to upper management.

which brings me to my question,  why are all the definitions for agile development so handwave-y, and where can i find a simple,  but technical description of agile?

Comment: Have you read the Agile Manifesto? Wikipedia is not the definition of agile.

Comment: @PhilipKendall  and books are not cats.  yet books should be able to tell you about cats.

Comment: @PhilipKendall but I've skimmed it,  and it seems more like a Christmas list for hiring developers than a rigid framework.

Comment: @tuskiomi Yep. You got it. Agile is not a rigid framework, because the people who formed it were not looking for another rigid framework. They already had prescriptive frameworks. They were looking for common ground, and skeptical of finding it at first.

Comment: It is also worth noting that while Agile is meant to be a series of values and principles, there are a number of frameworks and practices that are not as vague. Scrum, for example, provides a minimum framework to act as a scaffolding for a more complete development process. Specific practices, like TDD, also have very hard-and-fast rules (whether people follow them is another story)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because agile isn’t a framework. It’s a mindset.

**Individuals and interactions over processes and tools** - don’t tell your devs to follow some script. People should talk to each other, not be cogs in some machine.

**Working software over comprehensive documentation** - software matters, not the promise of software. Demos and examples work better than user guides nobody reads anyways.

**Customer collaboration over contract negotiation** - things work better when you work with customers rather than fight over what you agreed to do months ago.

**Responding to change over following a plan** - and this is really the crux of it. Agile accepts that humans can’t predict the future. Stuff changes. Requirements change. Technology changes. People get sick. People leave. So an agile mindset is one where you stop trying to plan for every eventuality; stop having a rigid plan up front for people to follow.

The mindset matters, not the steps you take.

Answer (score 7):

Agile is a [set of values](http://agilemanifesto.org/) and not a process framework. In fact, one of the major values is *individuals over processes* – rather than insisting on a rigid framework, find a way of working that works well for the people involved.

There are various frameworks in the agile-ish space that can be used to get started, most notably Scrum which is geared towards product development and consultancy projects. But these frameworks have little in common, beyond “review your process regularly and adapt it as needed”.

It is fair to describe agile as too vague to be helpful. And it is fair to ridicule the buzzword-laden “Agile-Industrial Complex” that has formed around these values (again, most notably with Scrum). I therefore recommend asking:

1. Should this software project be aligned with agile values? The answer can be legitimately “no”.
2. How can this software project express these values better? For example, how can we make it easier to respond to changing requirements?
3. We are not the first to try this. How can we learn from other people who are trying to live these values? This can mean adopting existing processes entirely, or experimenting with agile-ish techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The Agile Manifesto for Software Development is about a mindset shift and a cultural change. Per definition no simple technical definition of Agile in this realm.

**Agile is cultural transforming journey for all – individuals and the organisation**, with the goal of becoming agile i.e. change the culture of the organisation and the mindset of the individuals. ***If you don’t you’re just doing agile theatre***.

So in order to be prescriptive and technical you need to take these values & principles and describe for yourself – In order to use these as guidelines – what do we need to change?

Then start your change journey utilising some of the mentioned frameworks (best fit use combination – XP, Scrum/Kanban, Lean software development) as a starting point and a **organisational change methodology** e.g ( - in alphabetical order – numerous others can be found on the market - and you need to make sure the company helping you fits your organisation, your objectives and have the right people for the job):

[Kotters 8-Step Process to Accelerate Change](https://www.kotterinc.com/research-and-perspectives/8-steps-accelerating-change-ebook/)

[Prosci ADKAR](https://www.prosci.com/adkar)

[A Practical Guide for Evolving Agile and Resilient Organizations with Sociocracy 3.0 (PDF)](https://sociocracy30.org/_res/practical-guide/S3-practical-guide.pdf)